# Ways clear the list in c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a simple list

//here I have declared a static list

public static List list1 = new List();

here I can clear the list by using list.clear() method, Is there any other methods to clear the list.

Comment: What's the problem with using `list.clear()`? That's the most straightforward way to remove all the elements from the list.

Comment: It is the simplest way, and recommended way. If you are facing any problems  using that method please mention details.

Comment: Welcome to SO! if your question is about a language please tag it with the language.

Comment: Hereby I dont have any problem with .clear() method, However I have a bunch of list to clear.  So, to overcome to Bunch of .clear() code,  any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment you are trying to clear several lists. Where are the lists stored?

If they are stored in a collection named `lists`, you can clear all of them with:

```
foreach(var list in lists)
{
    list.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the List to `null` instead of calling `Clear`, with similar performance.

**But:**
After assigning to null, you must call the constructor again to avoid getting a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
list=null;
```

then all the list will be considered as empty or clear...
hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see no reason why you are not using `list.clear();`

It is the best way to do it.

Alternative, if you need,

is by removing each and every list element

```
int iCount=listToBeRemoved.items.count;

    foreach (int i=0;i<iCount;i++)
            {
                listToBeRemoved.Remove(i);
            }
```

Hope this helps..

**Note: I strongly recommend you to use list.Clear()**

Comment: your `foreach` is wield